# Can I run a 32-bit JVM on Yosemite?

Tags: java, jvm, 32-bit, jvm-arguments, osx-yosemite

I know similar questions have been asked, but they are unsatisfactory to me. I have the latest Java 8u60 (according to sysprefs), and when I run `java -d32`, it says:

> Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.

The Oracle JDK has no information on which package I need as there is only one (dmg/tar.gz) available.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why do you need 32bit jvm?

Comment: He might need it for some library. But as the posted answer says, 32-bit is not available. Check if the required library exists in 64-bit version.

Comment: Yes, I need it for liblsxbe.dylib, I've seen older postings stating it should work with -d32 but now that there is no compatible jvm, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 32 bit Java 8 for OS X. The possible choices are listed here:

[Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: yes, I see that, is that only for Java 8?  If I install Java 7, would the -d32 option be available?

Comment: Thanks for confirming.